# Where MT4 stores Profit calculation mode and Margin calculation mode parameters

Tags: metatrader4, mt4

I'm trying to figure out where MT4 stores the **Profit calculation mode** and **Margin calculation mode** parameters presented in this specification:
[image: MT4 contract specification]

I know that information about symbols is stored in the file **symbols.raw** and has : [format described here](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/constants/environment_state/marketinfoconstants#enum_symbol_calc_mode)

I was able to read this file and get other values, but I cannot find where the value ENUM_SYMBOL_CALC_MODE ( SYMBOL_CALC_MODE_FOREX, SYMBOL_CALC_MODE_FOREX_NO_LEVERAGE, etc.) is stored. Perhaps in another place?
I need to get this data NOT FROM MQL, and generally from a third party program, just by having access to the MT4 installation path.